# count character with react-hook-form watch

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, watch

Currently, I am using react-hook-form for form transmission.
and, I want to render the number of characters included in input and textarea.

The code I implemented is as follows.

```
<input
  id="title"
  type="text"
  placeholder="title"
  {...register('title', {
    required: true,
  })}
/>
<span>
  {watch('title').length}/20
</span>
```

As shown above, I tried to render the number of characters input through watch, but failed. How do you represent the number of characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update your watch with the condition for undefined.

```
{ watch('title') ? (watch('title').length)/20 : '' }
```

Can check working code from here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-095?file=src%2FApp.jsx

Comment: There's a minor error in your code. It should be:
`{ watch('title') ? \`${(watch('title').length)}/20\` : '' }`